# Backbone.model: Object function (a){return new n(a)} has no method 'has'

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I did wrote the following code(*)

When I try to run the following code(**) in my js console,
I get the following result:

```
"your attributes are: ", Object // json object taken from the server as I was expecting  

Object function (a){return new n(a)} has no method 'has'
```

Why do I get the issue about `has no method 'has'`?

-

(**)

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/"
});

require(["js/models/task"], function ( Model ) {
    var model = new Model({id: 1});
    model.fetch();
    console.log(model.attributes);
});
```

(*)

```
define([], function () {
    var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

        initialize: function ()
        {
            this.bind("change", function () {
                console.log("this model has been changed")
            });

            this.bind("error", function (model, error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
        },

        urlRoot: "/",
        url: function () {
            var base = this.urlRoot || (this.collection && this.collection.url) || "/";
            if (this.isNew()) return base;
            return base + this.id;
        },

        validate: function (attribute) {
            if (typeof attribute === "object") {
                console.log("your attributes are: ", attribute);
            }
        }

    });

    return MyModel;
});
```

Comment: It happend to me just today, updating Underscore to the last version fixed it.

Comment: Yes, it was just a problem of underscore version.

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` is asynchronous so try the following:

```
require(["js/models/task"], function ( Model ) {
    var model = new Model({id: 1});
    model.fetch({success: function() {
        console.log(model.attributes);
    }});

});
```

Comment: If I comment just the `console.log(model.attributes);` in your code I get the same error. So the problem is just when I perform the call `model.fetch();`

Comment: ok--do you have underscore included?  it's one of the dependencies of backbone

Comment: Sure, maybe it could be a problem of version. _.VERSION -> 1.3.0; Backbone.VERSION
"0.9.2"

Comment: From current page: "Backbone's only hard dependency is Underscore.js ( > 1.3.1). " so, definitely could be.